# PHP: A way to manually switch languages?

Tags: php, multilingual, language-switching

I have a website that has the following language switching algorithm:

- First, it detects the default browser language (I do not know why? but Chrome always gives something like `en-EN,ru,lv`, so Chrome's default language always is English, it seems).
- Then it writes the language value into a session variable `lang` and requests the desired string file (i.e. `/assets/includes/en-US/strings.php`);
- And every string from this file is being included in the HTML code, so the pure HTML has not any plain text in.

Of course, a default language detection is not the reason to stop - I need a manual language switcher like links (LV | EN | RU). So, what id the possible (and maybe the best) way to switch the language and to overwrite the session variable after user clicks to the desired language?

Comment: Can you not use an if statement to check if a new session i.e. chosen_session is set and if not use default_session

Comment: Can't you modify the switching algorithm? When user select manually a language, the value is saved in the session; the language algoritm checks this variable: if present it load the selected language, if not present will continue with actual behavior

Comment: I'm not sure about what your question is. Are you asking about the best GUI? (My Chrome sends `es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6`. It's configurable though it could hardly be more hidden.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is the simpliest way :)

```
$langs = array('LV', 'EN', 'RU');

<?php foreach ($langs as $lang): ?>
    <a href="index.php?lang=<?=$lang;?>"> <?=$lang;?> </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

so you give the user opportunity to change lang via GET in this example.

Overwrite the session to the sent request:

```
<?php
if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $langs) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // to prevent user to change its session to something you don't want to
}
?>
```

Afterwards you just interact with this session to display content.

You can use redirection, if you have each page written in different language:
(but I guess the logic how to interact with the language you have already implemented from the automatic language detection, but still... let me suggest some ways at fast?)

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] !== 'EN') {
    header("Location: mysite.com/".$_SESSION['lang']."/index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Or, you can use translation method.

All of your translations are in a database under columns with the same names as your $langs array.

So you output the content from this particular column:

```
SELECT lang_{$_SESSION['lang']} FROM translations WHERE string = '$string';
```

Comment: Use GET + POST will be better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I have absolutely the same HTML pages. The only difference is that they requests different strings.php files. Just because all the plain text is being written in those files.

Comment: So you just request the files depending on your session :) it seems your problem is solved